# What's the difference between tf.losses and tf.metrics?

Tags: tensorflow

In [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/estimators/abalone.py), `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` is used for the `loss` parameter of `EstimatorSpec`, while `tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error` is used for `eval_metric_ops` parameter.

Does anyone have ideas what is the main difference between `tf.loss` and `tf.metrics`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `tf.loss` ('s derivative) is used to update the model during backpropagation. `tf.metric`s are for evaluating the model.